"Run as administrator" vs. AD LastLogonDate
In my AD, I have 2 types of user accounts:

A regular one (let's call it CONTOSO\Panki) that is used to log into a client and run Office etc.
A separate user with local admin permissions on my client (let's say CONTOSO\Panki.admin) so I can configure settings etc.

All the local admin accounts (CONTOSO\$USER.admin) are in a seperate AD OU. In order to limit the risk posed by these users, I have written a script that checks the LastLogonDate against a specific timeframe and disables the account if it has not logged on within the time period.
I just noticed that when users use the .admin account with the "Run as Administrator" function, there is no logon event reported to AD.
I know that LastLogonTimestamp is not reliable and differs between DCs, but I've checked all my local DCs, and none of them are able to tell me that I used my panki.admin today to launch cmd.exe as administrator (not even our audit engine shows this logon).
My guess is that the Domain Cached Credentials are being used to confirm the admin credentials, instead of a domain controller.
Is it possible to have these "Run As" events reported to AD like a regular login?

LastLogonTimestamp and LastLogonDate are the same attribute and only accurate to within 14 days, but they do get replicated to each domain controller. You want LastLogon instead, which does update when doing a run-as-administrator action or anything that checks with the domain controllers.
The LastLogon attribute is not replicated, so you have to check each DC individually if you're not sure which one they used. Try something like this:
# iterate through each domain controller
$report = Foreach ($DC in (Get-ADDomainController -Filter * )) {
  # get the last logon times - change the username here
  Get-ADUser 'MyUser' -Properties LastLogonDate,LastLogon -Server $DC.Name |
    # make last logon readable
    Select @{n='ServerName';e={$DC.name}},Name,LastLogonDate,LastLogon,
      @{n='LastLogonAsDate';e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
}
# output as table
$report | Format-Table

It outputs the real last logon time from each domain controller, and you can see how the LastLogonDate lags behind:
ServerName  Name   LastLogonDate                  LastLogon LastLogonAsDate       
----------  ----   -------------                  --------- ---------------       
Server-DC01 MyUser 10/21/2024 7:00:36 PM 133747730636036025 10/30/2024 10:44:23 AM
Server-DC02 MyUser 10/21/2024 7:00:36 PM 133748638663138461 10/31/2024 11:57:46 AM

